# How can I speak English fluently in 45 days?

Tags: meaning, grammar, synonyms, names, subcontinental-english

I am new to start learning English. I want to improve my reading, writing & speaking english I have only 45 days to complete this course. Where I start learning. I am searching online for videos, ebooks but I think it's not enough.

Comment: Ask on https://ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: Duolingo is great in my opinion, as it combines elements of reading, listening, writing and speaking. If you do each skill with the word bank turned off, it's even better. Click on 'discuss' when you are unsure of certain phrasings as the comments can be really helpful

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's off-topic in asking something that is POB-only-answerable, and in being a request for resources. Try on LanguageLearners (I'm fairly sure it will be off-topic on ELL too).

Comment: Well for someone who's new to English, you're doing excellent so far. Bravo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Speaking any language *really* fluently in 45 days is  complete heresy if considered as a realizable possibility, so ridiculous that I can't see how it could be mentioned in any other context than that of jokes. It is particularly strange that you should believe in such a possibility as you possess already a strong base in English (unless someone else wrote your question for you) and must know how slow is  progress in learning a language. In 45 days, working night and day, you can't hope to accomplish more than providing yourself with a meagre vocabulary relative to basic necessities and that  will let you down three quarters of the time. Similarly, upgrading your English from a highschool level to a more literate level--more or less your problem--can in no way be a matter of a mere 45 days, that is also impossible: you are again talking abouts months, at least a couple of years of steady work in the language (listening, reading, talking if possible, and as well, writing).

The best I can advise you to do is to get yourself books concerning the domain in which you want to use your newly acquired skills in English; if literature is what you are interested in get some books on literary criticism and the literature you want to study itself, and read that. If sport is what you want to be able to speak and reflect about, the same principle is valid: read accounts from sports events and books about sport. If your interest is not specific but general and you are hoping to be become generally learned there is no end of your effort in reading and writing about anything and everything. Think of the native English speakers that have attained high proficiency levels in using their language: their achievements spell many highschool years of study, reading on the side, and several years of university education; there is no privileged fare for you either.

Comment: "Fluently" doesn't mean indistinguishably from a native speaker. Starting at OP's current level, 45 days of immersion learning ought to get them a heck of a way toward fluency.

Comment: @ThePhoton I don't believe so, and I even allow in that fluency occasional errors that an indigenous speaker of the language would not make. There aren't two definitions of fluency but one, give and take small departures from what you expect from a fluent native. I don't believe either that being a native means to be fluent: countless are the natives that will have great difficulties in expressing themselves fluently on particular subjects. There was a magazine article in an American magazine years ago titled "Why Johnny can't write?".